# Encode UIImage in iOS7 and Decode it in Java (Base64)

Tags: java, ios, swing, uiimage

I am trying to send a UIImage (taken from an iPhone's camera) to a Java Server and display it in a JFrame.

It might have something to do with the Encoding Option as the String in Xcode and Eclipse are slightly different. ex. the xCode string has "+" for spaces, but in Eclipse, it has " " for spaces.

**In Objective-C**

```
UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([temp objectForKey:@"photo"]);
NSString *base64StringOfImage = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

I then send this NSString in json to Java

**In Java**

```
byte[] imageBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(jsonPhoto.getString("photo"));
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
```

I get this error on the BufferedImage img line:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image data
```

If anyone can show me how to fix this, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
byte[] imageBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(jsonPhoto.getString("photo").replace(' ', '+'));
```

Comment: May I know which Base64 class are you using? I cannot find Base64 class in java 7.